# How to do BFS from multiple sources in Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm a Java SE and newbie in Neo4j, I meet this problem when I have to build an analysis graph for my project, any help or hint from you would be appreciated.

I have a simple directed graph in Neo4j.

Each node is denoted by Node{name:STRING} and the name of each node is unique, only one type of the relationship (s)-[:CONNECTED]->(t).

The size of the graph is 3M nodes and 8M edges.

And I was given a list of String, each String is the name of a source node.

I wondered may have a procedure to help me to do the BFS from all the source nodes at one time.

And of course, I want to find the fastest way (which could bring the best performance for my project) that can resolve this problem.

Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need the apoc.path.expandConfig. You can set the starting nodes, the relationship you want to traverse, and you can choose the BFS as well. Here there is an example

```
MATCH (p) WHERE p.name IN ["name1", "name2", "name3"]
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(p, {
    relationshipFilter: "CONNECTED>",
    minLevel: 1,
    maxLevel: 10,
    bfs:true
})
YIELD path
RETURN path, length(path) AS hops
ORDER BY hops;
```

Obviously I recommend you to read the documentation here:
https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.path/apoc.path.expandConfig/#path-expander-paths-config-examples-bfs-dfs